# Ionic side menu loses swipe-to-open when swipe-able list items are used

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building an app using the Ionic framework.

It has a side menu that opens from the left, and the main screen is a list of items that each have swipe-able options on the right. When the `ion-option-button` elements are added to the list items, I lose the ability to open the left side menu by swiping on top of the list items.

If I disable the `ion-option-button` elements (therefore creating static list items), I regain the ability to open my side menu via swipe.

How can I retain swiping ability to open both the side menu on the left and option buttons on the right of my list?

Comment: The ionic controls are very limited, so if your requirement falls outside their generic use cases, I would roll my own. Also unless you are prototyping I wouldn't use the ionic controls at all.

Comment: The reason behind my comment was that the `ion-option-button` is taking over the various touch events, and it could be quite a pain to figure out they are starting to be swiped left, so the event can be propagated to the menu. You could start by copying the `ion-option-button` source code, and modifying as you need.